# How do I assign the result of a regex match to a new variable, in a single line?

Tags: regex, perl

I want to match and assign to a variable in just one line:

```
my $abspath='/var/ftp/path/to/file.txt';

$abspath =~ #/var/ftp/(.*)$#;
my $relpath=$1;
```

I'm sure it must be easy.

Comment: *`just one line`* - Is there a special reason for that? You know that one-liners are not the best choice when catching non-nullable patterns.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
my ($relpath) = $abspath =~ m#/var/ftp/(.*)$#;
```

In list context the match returns the values of the groups.

Comment: Surely my favourite answer of all time on SO. I came here so many times...

Answer (score 18):

Obligatory Clippy: *"Hi! I see you are doing **path manipulation** in Perl. Do you want to use [Path::Class](http://p3rl.org/Path::Class) instead?"*

```
use Path::Class qw(file);
my $abspath = file '/var/ftp/path/to/file.txt';
my $relpath = $abspath->relative('/var/ftp');
# returns "path/to/file.txt" in string context
```

Comment: and this is why I follow SO, I always forget about Path::Class. Thanks

Answer (score 9):

You can accomplish it with the match and replace operator:

```
(my $relpath = $abspath ) =~ s#/var/ftp/(.*)#$1# ;
```

This code assigns `$abspath` to `$relpath` and then applies the regex on it.

**Edit:** Qtax answer is more elegant if you just need simple matches. If you ever need complex substitutions (as I usually need), just use my expression.

Answer (score 5):

With Perl 5.14 you can also use the `/r` (non destructive substitution) modifier:

```
perl -E'my $abspath="/var/ftp/path/to/file.txt"; \
        my $relpath= $abspath=~ s{/var/ftp/}{}r; \
        say "abspath: $abspath - relpath: $relpath"'
```

See "[New Features of Perl 5.14: Non-destructive Substitution](http://www.perl.com/pub/2011/05/new-features-of-perl-514-non-destructive-substitution.html)" for more examples.

Answer (score 0):

As you just want to remove the beginning of the string you could optimize the expression:

```
(my $relpath = $abspath) =~ s#^/var/ftp/##;
```

Or even:

```
my $relpath = substr($abspath, 9);
```