# How do I convert a full path to a relative path using perl?

Tags: perl

I have the full path to a file and the full path to one of its parent directories in two variables in Perl program.

What is a safe way to calculate the relative path of the file relative to the parent directory. Needs to work on windows and unix.

e.g.

```
$filePath = "/full/path/to/my/file";
$parentPath = "/full";
$relativePath = ??? # should be "path/to/my/file"
```

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278143/how-to-assign-result-of-a-regex-match-to-a-new-variable-in-a-single-line

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use **[File::Spec](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Spec.html)**

They have a **abs2rel** function

```
my $relativePath = File::Spec->abs2rel ($filePath,  $parentPath);
```

Will work on both Windows and Linux

Answer (score 10):

```
use Path::Class;
my $full = file( "/full/path/to/my/file" );
my $relative = $full->relative( "/full" );
```

Comment: +1 I like [Path::Class](http://p3rl.org/Path::Class), it papers over some design warts in File::Spec.

Comment: @daxim I realise this is a 12 year old comment, but any chance you recall what design warts there are/were in File::Spec that causes you to prefer Path::Class?