# Get path relative to home directory in perl

Tags: perl

For this problem I found one solution, but I am looking for alternative solutions.
Assume I am in directory

```
/home/user/testA/testB
```

and my home directory is `/home/user`, how can I obtain the path of the current directory relative to my home directory? That is: `testA/testB`.

I tried the following:

```
use Cwd qw(getcwd);
use Env qw(HOME);

my $cdir=getcwd;
my $p=$cdir=~s{^\Q$HOME\E/}{}r;
```

and it seems to work. My question is if there is a CPAN module for doing this? The closest I came was  `File::Spec::Functions qw(abs2rel)` but it just gives me `../..` .. maybe I missed something?

Comment: And what would you prefer to show as the output if cwd is `/usr/bin` and home dir is `/home/user`?

Comment: @devnull Not sure, I have not thought about that case actually.. maybe it could return `undef` in that case?

Comment: If you want `undef` in that case, then your current approach seems ok.  You actually want a __substring__ of the PATH.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8137286/how-do-i-convert-a-full-path-to-a-relative-path-using-perl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to work fine to me with `File::Spec`

```
#!usr/bin/perl

use File::Spec;

$base = '/home/user';
$path = '/home/user/testA/testB';

my $rel_path = File::Spec->abs2rel( $path, $base );
print($rel_path);
```

Output:

`testA/testB`

Comment: Thanks, it works! I think I must have mixed the order of the argument to `abs2rel`. If I change the order: `abs2rel($base,$path)` I get `../..` ..

Comment: Welcome. Yes. that looks correct. its the change of arguments thats giving value `../..`.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Path::Tiny](http://p3rl.org/Path%3a%3aTiny):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use Path::Tiny;

my $base = '/home/user';
my $path = '/home/user/testA/testB';

my $relative = path($path)->relative($base);
print "$relative\n";
```